# Live USB creator software

Tags: software-recommendation, live-usb, usb-creator

Is there a program that can make live USBs for any distro, iso, you get the point. I can only find ones that make live USBs for other linux distributions and none for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at UNetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Making a LiveUSB for Windows is doable depending on which version of Windows, but is tricky.

Comment: Yes I have, and the download the offical website gives is faulty and doesn't work. I'm trying to make a live usb for "Partition Wizard" and I don't think UNETBootin for with that either

Comment: karen, I'm looking for a universal live usb creator, not one that does strictly Linux OS's. I found one but forgot what it was called and can't find it anymore...